# How to read data in servlet from FirebaseDatabase

Tags: java, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database, servlet-3.0

How to read/fetch data(HttpResponse) from FireBase (real time database) in servlet

Below code is fetching from Realtime Database as HttpResponse_

```
public HttpResponse firebaseGet(String path) throws IOException {
    // Make requests auth'ed using Application Default Credentials
    Credential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(FIREBASE_SCOPES);
    HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);

    GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(path);

    return requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url).execute();
  }
```

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/firebase-tictactoe

Error:

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<h2>Error 401</h2>
```

Comment: There is nothing built in to Firebase for sending data to a `HttpResponse`. You'll have to take the data from Firebase's listeners (e.g. [`ValueEventListener.onDataChange` in the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once)) and put that into a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How to get response in servlet from Listeners

Comment: I'd imagine that would work the same way as in other contexts. Did you try anything already based on the documentation I linked?

Comment: document was not clear, How to read data from firebase datbase in servlet, (app engine)

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine#getting_started_with_firebase_realtime_database

Comment: The link you gave is for running a persistent listener. You're looking to use Firebase in a servlet, which is quite different. I gave you a link of what you're more likely to need to use. If you haven't added anything about Firebase to your servlet, we won't be able to help you better than the documentation I linked. I you tried adding Firebase to your servlet but got stuck, update your question to show what you tried.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, if you think that what you posted in your comments could be useful for others in the same situation, would you consider posting an answer to better explain what the solution to this problem is? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@FrankVanPuffelen's comments posted as an answer, using the "community wiki" option to confirm it is not mine:

There is nothing built in to Firebase for sending data to a `HttpResponse`. You'll have to take the data from Firebase's listeners (e.g. [`ValueEventListener.onDataChange` in the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once)) and put that into a `HttpResponse`.

You're looking to use Firebase in a servlet, which is quite different. I gave you a link of what you're more likely to need to use. If you haven't added anything about Firebase to your servlet, we won't be able to help you better than the documentation I linked. If you tried adding Firebase to your servlet but got stuck, update your question to show what you tried.